# WCF client HTTPS request exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, client

I am in the process of building a WCF client for a SOAP HTTPS webservice in .Net Core 2.1.

The service provider has supplied a .key and a .cert file which I have converted to a .p12 file using openssl. By adding this to a keystore I am able, through SoapUI, to successfully sent a request to the webservice (no other authentication than the certificate is required).

To do the same operation in .Net Core I have added a Connected Service to my project through the WCF wizard in Visual Studio. This service is based on the supplied service contract (WSDL file). I have then installed the .p12 certificate locally on my PC and I am using the following code to make the request. "MyService" is the connected service.

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://x.x.x.x:8300/MyService.asmx");
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<MyService>(binding, endpoint);    
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
        {
            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,                
            RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck,
            TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine
        };

channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
        StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
        StoreName.My,
        X509FindType.FindByIssuerName,
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");  

var service = channelFactory.CreateChannel(); 


ExecuteResponse response = service.Execute(new ExecuteRequest());
```

When running this code I am getting the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'.'

The strange thing is that I am allowed to make the request if I use the HttpClientHandler which tells me that there must be a mismatch between the underlying structure of the two implementations.
Anyone who knows how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate might just be used to establish the trust relationship between the client-side and the server-side.
For making a successful call to the service, we should keep the binding type between the client-side and the server-side consistent. Therefore, I would like to know the automatically generated client-side configuration by Adding service reference, please post the `System.servicemodel` section located in the `appconfig` of the client project.
[image]
If the server authenticates the client-side with a certificate, the error typically indicates the trust relationship has not established yet between the client-side and the server-side.
On the client-side, we should install the server certificate in the `LocalCA`. On the server-side, we should install the client certificate in the `LocalCA` certificate store.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: The service is not added as a service reference but as a connected service. I have tried installing the certificate in the Intermediate Certification Authorities folder, but it does nto solve the problem. Unfortunately, I have no control over the server side and only limited knowledge about how certificates are handled. However, I do believe that it relates to the specific dotnet core implementation since I am able to make the request through SoapUI.

Comment: yeah. there is no difference between these ways. Have you found the client configuration in the `Reference.cs`? the generated binding type must be consistent with the server-side. It is unnecessary to program the constructor parameter. It might be a mismatch with the server-side. Besides, please try to install both certificates in LocalCA(Trusted Root Certification Authorities).

Comment: Then We use serviceclient to configure the service certificate and client certificate 
          ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();            client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.Root, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c");
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "9ee8be61d875bd6e1108c98b590386d0a489a9ca");

Comment: I think I have come to the conclusion that the problem is related to the server configuration and since I am not able to make any changes to this I have been forced to go in another direction. I am now using the an HttpClient instead which apparently have a different underlying HTTP handling than a WCF service.